# How to query the presence of an element inside a Spark Dataframe Column that contains a set?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe where one column has the type `Set<text>`.
This column contains a set of string, for example `["eenie","meenie","mo"]`. 
How do I filter the contents of the whole dataframe so that
I only get those rows that (for example) contain the value `eenie` in the set?

I'm looking for something similar to

`dataframe.where($"list".contains("eenie"))`

the above shown example is only valid for when the content of column list is a string not a Set. What alternatives are there to fit my circumstances?

Edit: My question is not a duplicate. The user in that question has a set of values and wants to know which ones are located inside a specific column. I have a column that contains a set, and I want to know if a specific value is part of the set. My approach is the opposite of that.

Comment: Spark SQL has no `Set<text>` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_contains

dataframe.where(array_contains($"list", "eenie"))
```